# Using Loops to decorate multiple imported functions in Python

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I am new to Python and decorators, so apologies if this seems to be a trivial question.

I am trying to apply decorators to multiple imported functions using a loop in Python as shown below

```
from random import random, randint, choice

def our_decorator(func):
    def function_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Before calling " + func.__name__)
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print(res)
        print("After calling " + func.__name__)
    return function_wrapper

for f in [random, randint, choice]:
    f = our_decorator(f)

random()
randint(3, 8)
choice([4, 5, 6])
```

Ideally, I expect the output to be in this form :

```
Before calling random
<random_value>
After calling random
Before calling randint
<random_integer>
After calling randint
Before calling choice
<random_choice>
After calling choice
```

But, I am only getting the result of the choice function as the output.

```
<random_choice among 4,5 6>
```

The decorator has not been applied to any of the functions and it also looks like the random() and the randint(3,8) calls are not getting executed.

I  would like to know, what is going wrong here and what can be done to decorate multiple imported functions using loops?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your are decorating the functions and then binding the name `f` to each of them in turn. So after the loop, `f` will be equal to the last decorated function. The original names for the original functions are unaffected.

You'll have to work with the names, something like

```
gl = globals()
for f_name in ['random', 'randint', 'choice']:
    gl[f_name] = our_decorator(gl[f_name])
```

But I would *much* prefer to just apply the decorator to each function in turn by hand.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Remco & Willem that using the @ syntax in the usual way would be better, although Willem's approach of modifying the attributes of the imported `random` module is probably better than man-handling `globals()`. But here's another way:

```
from random import random, randint, choice

def our_decorator(func):
    def function_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Before calling " + func.__name__)
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print(res)
        print("After calling " + func.__name__)
    return function_wrapper

random, randint, choice = [our_decorator(f) for f in (random, randint, choice)]

random()
randint(3, 8)
choice([4, 5, 6])
```

**output**

```
Before calling random
0.8171920550436872
After calling random
Before calling randint
8
After calling randint
Before calling choice
4
After calling choice
```

---

In the comments, RemcoGerlich points out that Willem Van Onsem's technique of decorating the attributes of the `random` module means that any other imported modules that use the decorated functions in `random` will also be affected. That's perfectly correct if the other module uses the standard `import random` statement. I guess that in some circumstances that behaviour may actually be desirable.

However, there is a way that if you have control over the code in the other module. If the other module uses the `from random import choice` form, then it will get the undecorated version of `choice`. Here's a short demo.

**dectest.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from random import choice

def test(seq):
    print('In test')
    return choice(seq)
```

```
import random
import dectest

def our_decorator(func):
    def function_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Before calling " + func.__name__)
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print(res)
        print("After calling " + func.__name__)
        return res
    return function_wrapper

f = 'choice'
setattr(random, f, our_decorator(getattr(random, f)))

a = [4, 5, 6, 7]
print(random.choice(a))

print('dectest')
print(dectest.test(a))
```

**typical output**

```
Before calling choice
6
After calling choice
6
dectest
In test
7
```

---

If **dectest.py** looks like this:

```
import random

def test(seq):
    print('In test')
    return random.choice(seq)
```

then we get the behaviour that Remco mentions:

```
Before calling choice
5
After calling choice
5
dectest
In test
Before calling choice
4
After calling choice
4
```

Comment: But actually changing the functions in the random module also changes other libraries that happen to use that module, that may be dangerous. Globals() is unusual and a sign of doing things that are probably unnecessary, but it's not particularly dangerous.

Comment: As far as I know this does not change the function *globally*: you only set different functions for the current file.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: yes this does, but your solution actually changes the functions in the random module, other code will see it too.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: well as far as I know that is the intended behavior: calling a decorator like you would have called it in the module it yourself.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Good point! I didn't think of that... OTOH, if the other module uses a `from import` then it won't be affected. I'll add a small example to my answer. But of course you can't rely on the other module doing that, unless you code it yourself.

Comment: @PM2Ring: if it uses `from import`, then it will depend on which module was imported first.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich In my tests when using `from random import choice` in `dectest.py` it makes no difference whether I import `random` or `dectest` first in the main script, if I put the `import` statements at the top of the script. However, if I import `dectest` _after_ applying the decorator then `dectest.test` uses the decorated version of `choice`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by setting it for the `random` package like:

```
import random

for f in ['random','randint','choice']:
    setattr(random,f,our_decorator(getattr(random,f)))
```

Here you thus set the "attribute" of the `random` package. Also note that in your `for` loop, you feed strings.

and then call with:

```
random.random()
random.randint(3, 8)
random.choice([4, 5, 6])
```

Nevertheless, this does not look very elegant. A decorator is usually applied by using the `@`-syntax on the function itself.